# Reloading option in a select list with ajax

Tags: 7, ajax

So here is my problem:

I have a form so users can create orders. There is a 'Client' select list where they can select the client of the order. When we select a client, we use ajax to load client info (address, tax rate, discount ...) and populate some field. This works fine.

I am now adding a feature to be able to create directly a client from the order, in a modal.
So I have a button in the order form, that triggers ajax to open a modal and render the new client form:

```
  $account_form = drupal_get_form('mymodule_creation_account_custom_form',$form['field_client']);
  $output = drupal_render($account_form);

  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('div#createClientModal','foundation',array('reveal', 'open'));
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#new-account-form-placeholder',$output);
  return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => $commands,
  );
```

Then I fill in the info, and submit the account from the modal:

```
  $account = my_module_new_account_form_submit($form, $form_state);

  $form['client_hidden_field']['und']['#options'][$account->nid] = $account->title;
  $form['client_hidden_field']['und']['#default_value'] = $form['client_hidden_field']['und']['#value'] = $account->nid;

  $commands = array();
  // Closing the modal
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('div#createClientModal','foundation',array('reveal', 'close'));
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('.field-name-field-client', render($form['client_hidden_field']));
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('.field-name-field-client select','change');

  // Replace the form with an empty div
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('div#account-form-wrapper','<div id="new-account-form-placeholder"></div>');

  return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => $commands
  );
```

So what I am doing in this last submit, is creating the new account (that works), it returns me the nid. Then, as I have stored in a variable ($form['client_hidden_field']) the client field, I update it with the new option, select the option, replace the old client select list with the new one, and trigger change to call the old callback that loads a client info when it is selected.

I have tried lots of thing and each time I select the new client created, I get an 'Illegal choice'. I have tried without default value, without triggering a 'change', in JS with a command_invoke and nothings seems to work.

The only success I had was :
I do all these step, I manually select a client (one already existing before), and then select the new one. After that I didn't have the 'Illegal choice' and was able to save. But this is not a way to make it work.

If someone has any idea, I would love your help !

Thanks

Ed

Comment: I think this is a good place to understand a bit better where I am wrong: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/resolve-the-error-an-illegal-choice-has-been-detected

But because the second ajax callback is about the second $form in the modal, it returns me the new refreshed field, in the modal, not replacing the previous one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was finally able to succeed this. I didn't manage to return the new field to the form properly (cf. [Resolve the error "An illegal choice has been detected..."](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/resolve-the-error-an-illegal-choice-has-been-detected)) because I am working with two forms (and maybe I am missing something).

So skipping the validation for that field in form.inc seems to be the only solution that I have. And the only way I found was to add a function in #after_build to unset '#needs_validation':

In form_alter:

```
array_unshift($form['field_client']['und']['#after_build'],'remove_client_validation');
```

And the function:

```
function remove_client_validation($form_element) {
  unset($form_element['#needs_validation']);
  return $form_element;
}
```

Thanks to: [I use jQuery to alter the exposed form select options. Got error: "An illegal choice has been detected." How to bypass validation?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48791/i-use-jquery-to-alter-the-exposed-form-select-options-got-error-an-illegal-ch), where I found that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `$form_state['rebuild']=TRUE`. It will help you to update your changes while adding new client.

Comment: Where would you add it? It should be when the modal close I guess, but at this point, my $form and $form_state are the one from new client form in the modal.

Comment: You should right it in hook_submit. your current submit hook hook as mention above. you code put it after this line:`$form['client_hidden_field']['und']['#default_value'] = $form['client_hidden_field']['und']['#value'] = $account->nid;`